# It's a long row ahead, boys

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, geography

> Jeff's company advanced slowly, aware of the presence a rare crocodile species on the long river. Jackson had his wallet in hand and was admiring some foreign banknotes. "This Japanese currency, I say! Check out the golden colour!"
>
> Nobody seemed interested. At the moment they were more focused on observing the organizational behaviour of some carnivorous fish in the ship's wake. The Zairian jungles were filled with exciting lifeforms.
>
> One of the men was babbling on about the romantic love he felt for a woman back home. Her name was... umm...

What was the woman's name?

Hint:

> Jeff is very famous.

Hint #2:

> His company is even more famous.

Hint #3:

> The crocodile species isn't really rare at all. "Rare" just fit the story a little better.

Comment: Could the woman's name be England? Colour is English spelling, so maybe he missed England a lot

Comment: It's just the way I spell it :)

Comment: (+1) for Canadian spelling, eh? :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The woman's name was ...

> ... **LENA**.

The story refers to ...

> ... the longest rivers of the world:
>
>  • **Amazon** is Jeff Bezos's company.
>  • One species of crocodile is the **Nile** crocodile.
>  • **Yangtze** means "long river" in Chinese.
>  • Jackson is the capital of **Mississippi**.
>  • **Yenisei** sounds like "Yen, I say."
>  • The **Yellow River** is named for its golden colour.
>  • **OB** means organizational behaviour.
>  • **Paraná** sounds a bit like piranha, a carnivorous fish.
>  • Zaire is another name for the **Congo** river.
>  • **Amur** sounds like *amour*, romantic love.
>  • Finally, **Lena** is a girl's name.

Comment: Aaand we have a winner. Well done!

Answer (score 2):

I think that the answer has to do with

> the fact that each sentence represents two words that start with the same letter.

Jeff's company advanced slowly, aware of the presence a rare crocodile species on the long river. *(edited)*

> Jeff is referring to Jeff *Bezos*, whose company is *Amazon*, a long river. American crocodiles (although black caimans are found more regionally) are a rare crocodile species found by that river. So we still have two As...

Jackson had his wallet in hand and was admiring some foreign banknotes. "This Japanese currency, I say! Check out the golden colour!"

> This could be talking about **yellow yen**. *Although this was the first clue I thought I found, I don't understand the reference to Jackson though...maybe Andrew Jackson, on the American $20; or Michael Jackson, who sang the song "Money"...?*

Nobody seemed interested. At the moment they were more focused on observing the organizational behaviour of some carnivorous fish in the ship's wake.

> This could be the **psychology** of the **piranhas**. *I think this is one of the correct clues...*

The Zairian jungles were filled with exciting lifeforms.

> This could be the **critters** or **creatures** in the **Congo**. (Exciting trivia, the *Rumble in the Jungle* happened in Zaire's capital, Kinshasa, between George Foreman and Muhammad Ali!) *I think this is something with the Congo, if not creatures...*

At any rate, another word for romantic love could be

> Adoration, which means that the man could have been talking about **adoration** of **Abigail**? Or another girl's name that starts with A?

Comment: This isn't the intended answer, but she sounds like a lovely lady.

Comment: @jafe Is my reasoning close or am I pretty far off?

Comment: There's a different theme that you're missing. I've added a tag.

Comment: That said, you have already found some of the correct clues. Not saying which ones though :)

Answer (score 2):

Possible partial answer:

Looks like all the story components of the first part have a pretty strong connection with

> **Gold**, which is also directly mentioned in the story.

In particular,

Jeff's company advanced slowly,

> *Jeff* **Gold**blum is a famous actor

aware of the presence a rare crocodile species

> A [**Golden** *crocodile*](http://bransonswildworld.com/golden-crocodile/) is indeed pretty rare, with roughly 250 of them still living in the wild.

on the long river.

> There are annoyingly many [**golden** *rivers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_River)

Jackson had his wallet in hand

> **Gold** is a 2008 compilation album of Michael *Jackson*'s music

and was admiring some foreign banknotes. "This Japanese currency, I say!

> The *Japanese* word for *money*, "kane" is written 金, which also means "**gold**"

Check out the golden colour!"

> Ah, well, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjA5A86V6SY#t=1

Comment: I have to say these fit amazingly well (even though it's coincidental). The link in the end is a nice touch.